# intents not working on discord.py commands extension

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use intents on my discord bots so I can get all members. I looked through a few posts and read that I'm supposed to do

```
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, members=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)
```

However when I try it, it says `NameError: name 'discord' is not defined`. I don't know how to solve it and why works for other people.
I also have "Server Members Intent" ticked.

I've tried putting `import discord` at the top but it return `None` if I print the guild or member list (it only shows the info for the bot itself, the other users it just says "None").

Comment: Your second question has nothing to do with the intents or the import, you simply has to **start** the bot. Perhaps first check the quick start example on starting a dpy bot: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: @Taku the part that tries to get the guild and members is in the `on_ready` function.

Comment: Ah maybe edit that into the question since it sounded like you never ran the bot and tried printing the attributes. Regardless, in that case, you'll need the guilds intent as well, just set it to True on the second line of your code sample. The guilds intent is required for both populating the guilds and members cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have imported only the commands extension, you have to import discord fully too, simply add this to the top of your file

```
import discord
...
```

Comment: Doing so returns "None" for everything except the bot itself (the guild and the member list).

Comment: Have you enabled the intents in the discord application settings?
You can also check the [docs for intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)

Comment: yes, I have, it says so in the post.